# How to express this XML by json schema?

Tags: xml, jsonschema

How to express this XML by json schema?

```
<students>
    <student name="jack">
        <age>23</age>
        <address>
            <city>new town</city>
            <street>my home street 105.</street>
        </address>
    </student>
</students>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you want:

```
{
  "students": {
    "student": {
      "-name": "jack",
      "age": "23",
      "address": {
        "city": "new town",
        "street": "my home street 105."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In addition, let me show you a *[little secret](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.UXYP8ysjqp0)* ;)

Now, for json schema:

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema", "id": "http://jsonschema.net", "required": false, "type": "object", "properties":{
  [-]"students":{
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/students", "required": false, "type": "object", "properties":{
      [-]"student":{
          "id": "http://jsonschema.net/students/student", "required": false, "type": "object", "properties":{
          [-]"-name":{
          "id": "http://jsonschema.net/students/student/-name", "required": false, "default": "jack", "type":"string"}
          ,[-]"address":{
              "id": "http://jsonschema.net/students/student/address", "required": false, "type": "object", "properties":{
              [-]"city":{
              "id": "http://jsonschema.net/students/student/address/city", "required": false, "default": "new town", "type":"string"}
              ,[-]"street":{
              "id": "http://jsonschema.net/students/student/address/street", "required": false, "default": "my home street 105.", "type":"string"}
            }
            }
          ,[-]"age":{
          "id": "http://jsonschema.net/students/student/age", "required": false, "default": "23", "type":"string"}
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for the identation, I'm working with limited tools here.
And now for *[secret #2](http://www.jsonschema.net/)*

Comment: this's a json, but i want a json-schema, also thanks you so much!

Comment: @jychan check it out again ;)

Comment: how to distinguish the property 'name' and the element 'age'?